# Why is this code running?

Tags: c++, c, wndproc

I wrote the following WndProc. It is used by a Notify Icon. I removed the unimportant parts (like default labels) for an better overview.

When I click the Nofify Icon with the right mouse button, the context menu appears. When I click an item, I get the corresponding return value of TrackPopupMenu and print it out. However, TrackPopupMenu is a blocking call, but the WndProc is just working fine while the context menu is opened. Why?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
        AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, ID_TRAY_EXIT_CONTEXT_MENU_ITEM, displayString);
    }
         break;
    case WM_TRAYICON:
        switch (lParam)
        {
        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        {
            POINT curPoint;
            GetCursorPos(&curPoint);
            UINT clicked = TrackPopupMenu(
                hMenu,
                TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_NONOTIFY,
                curPoint.x,
                curPoint.y,
                0,
                hWnd,
                NULL
                );

            std::cout << std::to_string(clicked) << std::endl;
        }
            break;
        }
        std::cout << lParam << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `TrackPopupMenu` is pumping messages while it is executing. That is, it has a message processing loop that calls `DispatchMessage` for any new messages posted to the thread's message queue, and `DispatchMessage` in turn calls your window procedures with the messages intended for each window.